# src attribute is undefined after fetching and displaying data after an ajax get request is made to flickr.photos.search API

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

I find this problem particulary interesting because I am recieving the data back from the server, which is being passing into an array. I know that I am getting back the data after logging to the console the `photoGallery` array. However, in the `displayImage()` function, after the html has been added, the src attributes inside the figure are undefined. Any clues?

[Undefined Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07dB9.png) 
[PhotoGalleryArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73q6m.png)

Here is some example code:

```
let photoGallery = [];
let searchRequests;
let searchReceived;

$(document).ready(function () {
    let searchArray = ["dog", "cat", "horse", "tree", "bug"];
    searchFlickr(searchArray);
});
```

After the document loads, the searchFlickr function is called

```
function searchFlickr(searchArray) {
    photoGallery = [];
    searchRequests = searchArray.length;
    searchReceived = 0;
    let flickr_searchStr = "";
    $('#Gallery figure').fadeOut();
    searchArray.forEach(function (element) {
        flickr_searchStr = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&sort=relevance&content_type=7&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&per_page=1&text=" + element + API_KEY
        $.get(flickr_searchStr, function (data) {
            fetchImage(data);
        })
    })
}
```

For each `jSON` object we get back, the `fetchImage` function is called

```
function fetchImage(data) {
    searchReceived++
    for (let i = 0; i < data.photos.photo.length; i++) {
        let imageObject = {id: data.photos.photo[i].id,title: data.photos.photo[i].title}
        photoGallery.push(imageObject);
        getSizes(imageObject);
    }
}

function getSizes(imageObject) {
    let getSizesStr = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&format=json&nojsoncallback=1" + API_KEY + "&photo_id=" + imageObject.id;
    $.get(getSizesStr, function (data) {

        imageObject.url_small = data.sizes.size[3].source;
        //Check if searchRecieved is equal to the length of photosRequests then call displayImage function
        if (searchReceived == searchRequests) {
            displayImage(photoGallery);
        }
    });
}
```

This is where I cannot figure out what is going on, if you `console.log(photoGallery)`, you will get back the array of data. But after loop has finished only one image actually has a url in the src attribute, the rest are undefined.

```
function displayImage(photoGallery) {
    let htmlStr = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < photoGallery.length; i++) {
        htmlStr += `<figure><img src="${photoGallery[i].url_small}"><figcaption>${photoGallery[i].title}</figcaption></figure>`;
    }
    $('#Gallery').html(htmlStr);
    $('#Gallery figure').fadeIn(500);
}
```

EDIT - The jSON object passed to the `fetchImage()` function looks like this:

```
{ "photos": { "page": 1, "pages": "432757", "perpage": 1, "total": "432757", 
"photo": [
  { "id": "42046641202", "owner": "65984184@N05", "secret": "e94c9e7c26", "server": "910", "farm": 1, "title": "Painted Dogs", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 }
] }, "stat": "ok" }
```

EDIT - The jSON object called in the `getSizes()` function looks like this:

```
{ "sizes": { "canblog": 0, "canprint": 0, "candownload": 0, 
    "size": [
      { "label": "Square", "width": 75, "height": 75, "source": "https:\/\/farm6.staticflickr.com\/5254\/5412377706_d77700fc38_s.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/parismadrid\/5412377706\/sizes\/sq\/", "media": "photo" },
      { "label": "Large Square", "width": "150", "height": "150", "source": "https:\/\/farm6.staticflickr.com\/5254\/5412377706_d77700fc38_q.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/parismadrid\/5412377706\/sizes\/q\/", "media": "photo" },
      { "label": "Thumbnail", "width": 100, "height": 67, "source": "https:\/\/farm6.staticflickr.com\/5254\/5412377706_d77700fc38_t.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/parismadrid\/5412377706\/sizes\/t\/", "media": "photo" },
      { "label": "Small", "width": "240", "height": "160", "source": "https:\/\/farm6.staticflickr.com\/5254\/5412377706_d77700fc38_m.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/parismadrid\/5412377706\/sizes\/s\/", "media": "photo" },
      { "label": "Small 320", "width": "320", "height": "213", "source": "https:\/\/farm6.staticflickr.com\/5254\/5412377706_d77700fc38_n.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/parismadrid\/5412377706\/sizes\/n\/", "media": "photo" },
      { "label": "Medium", "width": "500", "height": "333", "source": "https:\/\/farm6.staticflickr.com\/5254\/5412377706_d77700fc38.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/parismadrid\/5412377706\/sizes\/m\/", "media": "photo" },
      { "label": "Medium 640", "width": "640", "height": "426", "source": "https:\/\/farm6.staticflickr.com\/5254\/5412377706_d77700fc38_z.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/parismadrid\/5412377706\/sizes\/z\/", "media": "photo" },
      { "label": "Large", "width": "1024", "height": "682", "source": "https:\/\/farm6.staticflickr.com\/5254\/5412377706_d77700fc38_b.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/parismadrid\/5412377706\/sizes\/l\/", "media": "photo" }
    ] }, "stat": "ok" }
```

Comment: can you show a sample response json that you are receiving

Comment: and every time it returns you the json does it have the same set of properties?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: I'm only using example code, the real code checks to see if I am receiving the same set of properties. So I know that is not the problem.

Comment: hmm are you talking about the `url_small` being undefined when you are iterating over the `photoGallery` object that you have created isnt it ?

Comment: Yes, it sometimes works and other times it doesn't, which is why I believe its a timing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a weird one but looks like if you define the property `url_small` when you are creating the object `imageObject`, will remove the exception, I just tested it locally and I thought initially that may be using `Object.definProperty()` to add a new property to the object `imageObject` might fix this issue along with using `for..in` loop with `Object.hasOwnProperty()` check but nothing seemed to work unless I define the property at the time of declaring the object and then adding the value to it inside `getSizes()`.

Change your object in the `fetchImage()` to the following

```
let imageObject = {
    id: data.photos.photo[i].id,
    title: data.photos.photo[i].title,
    url_small: ''
}
```

Comment: I actually just figured out the problem. It's a timing issue. I ended up putting the call to the displayImage function in a setTimeout function and it worked. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I also forgot to clarify, if you are testing locally, you are going to need your own API key which I did not provide in the example code (I'm assuming you have your own). I took your advice to remove the exception. Thank You.

Comment: glad to hear you fixed it, yes I did test with my API key, @JimGriffith , you can mark the answer as correct if it helped you out solve the problem